# How to Resolve Recaptcha Python3 Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, captcha

I have the following code written in Python3, it is a robot that enters a site to capture information; However, before adding the token detail, I get an alert for a recaptcha challenge. The challenge is not always shown, sometimes just clicking on the captcha check progresses, however on other occasions it asks me to complete the recaptcha challenge. This is my code:

```
#PAGE driver.get("url")
#LOGIN
step = 'step_1;01_-_Login'
timeInit = time.time()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys("user")  
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("Pass")
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

#CAPTCHA
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".recaptcha-checkbox-border").click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Capture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl11y.jpg)

How could I solve this problem?. I am using the following applications:

- Selenium
- Python3
- geckodriver

Comment: The whole point of CAPTCHA is to prevent you from doing this.

Comment: Try using a user profile with selenium. Login once manually solving the captcha and select "remember me". Odds are you can skip the login/captcha at least for a while. Otherwise there are paid APIs that solve google captchas but I doubt you want to go down that route.